# I want a certain Ion in my solution. How do I choose which chemical to buy?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solubility

thanks for taking the time. I am physicist doing experiments in which I need certain Ions (at the moment, Ru(II)) in solution. I have no chemical training excepting what I'm learning right now. What I need is a research strategy on how to find which salts or compounds containing Ru(II) will dissolve in water in such a way, that the Ru ions are available to the biological system that I'm studying. Do you have any resources that you could point my way or any good starting points? Thank you again

Comment: There are only so many chemical elements out there, and you couldn't possibly be the first who thought of introducing Ru at biological systems. Look at your predecessors, and do the same.

Comment: This may assist  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1878535216301198

Comment: Thank you you two, I totally agree that I could google procedures for every trace metall I want to try, its more about finding a general strategy for someone new to chemistry. If there isn't one, thats fine too obviously